# How do I print the same value repeatedly?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am able to display t to the screen but every time the loop iterates, the current value of t is added to the previous value before printing. This means, it prints out 9,18,27,36... How do I avoid this? I need it to display 9 continually as long as the code loops.

```
int d,i,p,s,t,arr[30];
float hp = 0;
float arr2[30];
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
    for (d = 0; d < 360; d++){
          if (sin(d*(PI/180))+1 + sin(d*(2*PI/180))+1> sin((d-1)*(PI/180))+1 
+ sin((d-1)*(2*PI/180))+1 && sin(d*(PI/180))+1 + sin(d*(2*PI/180))+1 > 
sin((d+1)*(PI/180))+1 + sin((d+1)*(2*PI/180))+1){
         arr2[i++] = sin(d*(PI/180))+1 + sin(d*(2*PI/180))+1;
        }
      }
for (p = 0;p <30; p++){
  if(arr2[p]!=0){
    if (arr2[p]>hp){
    hp = arr2[p];  
    }  
  } 
}
for (d = 0; d < 3600; d++){
      if (sin(d*(PI/180))+1 + sin(d*(2*PI/180))+1 >= hp){
         arr[s++] = d;
        }
      }
 for (s = 0; s < 30; s++){
  if (arr[s]!=0){
    t++;
   }
  } 
  Serial.println(t);
}
```

Comment: Properly formatting the code will increase readability tremendously...

Comment: If it is about counting the values in `arr` unequal to 0 each time newly, then simply set `t` to 0 before the counting loop.

Comment: I'll work on proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A general advice:

> Define variables with the smallest scope possible. In your case, unless there is a reason to make `t` and `d` global variables, don't make them global variables. Make them function local variables.

Change your code to:

```
void loop(){
   int t = 0;
   int d = 0;

   ...

   Serial.println(t);
}
```

This will solve your immediate problem and, more importantly, your code will be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I'll keep your advice in mind.